# is it possible to apply car detection on IMAGE using haar cascade method in OpenCV?

Tags: java, android, opencv, computer-vision, face-detection

If it is possible than it will detect car once or blinking multiple time on single car
i have done car detection on live feed but it is detecting car and just continue blinking so i need to use it on image. I have already Haar .xml file.
Thanx in advance

Comment: could you explain your situation a bit better ? it's not clear, where you got stuck or what went wrong.

Comment: do you mean "blinking" (= detecting a car?) multiple times on a single image or multiple times during the video (for example blinking once on each of 25 images in a second)?

Comment: Exactly my green detection rectangle is blinking on detected object in video so i want to prevent it.
i just want that to detect once only (actually i m using the value of number of occurrence of detection to count the cars, so this blinking is making such a big value in my count variable)

Comment: when a rectangle forms than count variable = count + 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compare the center of the detection rectangle from the previous frame to that in the current frame. If the center has not changed too much, it is likely the same object. In that case, don't count the "new" rectangle in the current frame.

Comment: we are new in opencv so can you please explain little bit, or can you please give us some idea about it ... i will be thankful to you for this

Comment: OpenCV should return the x and y of the upper left, and the height and width of the rectangle. You can use these values to find the center of the rectangle. You'll need some sort of global set of objects. Each time a new rectangle is found compare it to all objects in the global set. If the centers are less than, for example, 10 pixels (Cartesian), then update the object in the global set with the new position. If the new rectangle center is farther away, then it is a new object and should be added to the global set.